# How to optimize/change a "searching" program Java

Tags: java, optimization, random

I have written some java code to determine the sum of what three cubes give you a given number. (Sorry I'm really not sure how to explain what it does, the code is rather simple though.) And the problem is, when searching for numbers between -100 and 100 the code runs very quick. But when searching a bigger area, (thousands or ten-thousands etc) It starts to run very slow, even when looking for small numbers. What I am asking are for ways to optimize it, and maybe ways to have it search more systematically, starting at small integers and working its way up to bigger ones, rather than how it does it now which is to pick random ones and check them with the answer.

Here is the code:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int want = -69;
        double test;
        boolean found = false;
        int answer;
        while(found == false)
        {
            int max = 100;
            int min = max / 2;
            int a = (int) (Math.random()*max - min);
            int b = (int) (Math.random()*max - min);
            int c = (int) (Math.random()*max - min);
            test = Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3) + Math.pow(c, 3);
            answer = (int) test;
            if(answer == want) {
                found = true;
                System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this sentence : "I have written some java code to determine the sum of what three cubes give you a given number. "

Comment: Sorry, I know it is hard to read, I had a hard time describing it. Let my try again. The code takes the sum of three cubes, in the variable "want" and it attempts to work backwards and find the original integers that were cubed and summed. In the code, it is using -69, which it then finds the original numbers to be 4, -5 and -2. Please let me know if further clarification is needed. Thanks

Comment: But  a,b and c are random numbers, it may take for ever without finding a,b,c such that a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = want.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is impossible, but if you put in specific numbers that you calculate before hand (as this is a very primitive program) and they are all less than 100, it will find the numbers very quickly, it is only when you get to large numbers that it takes long periods of time. And if there are no solutions, then no, it does not handle that well at all.

Comment: I guess your problem is not hte code, but the algorithm. By just searching randomly, you span up the full range of numbers within this range, regardless how small your "want" is. Because you have three random numbers, your room for poossible combinations increases cubicly. So if lets say with 100 it takes 10 seconds, with thousand it will take 100seconds i. e. a quarter of an hour, and with ten thousand 3 weeks.

Comment: Yes, I am currently trying to limit the search by telling it which ones it already searched by making an array for each of the three variables and adding to it with a for loop. I don't know if that is the best way to do it or not. If anyone has a better idea please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally not an easy problem. A more systematic way of doing this would be to test every possible combination of a,b and c within a given range of values for a,b and c. Like this:

```
public class Main{
    static boolean foundSolution = false;

    public static void main(String []args){
        int limit = 10;
        boolean[][][] alreadyChecked = new boolean[limit*2+1][limit*2+1][limit*2+1];
        foundSolution = false;
        printCubesOfNum(-69,limit,0,0,0,alreadyChecked);
    }

    public static void printCubesOfNum(int answer,int limit, int a, int b, int c,boolean[][][] alreadyChecked) {
        if(!foundSolution && !alreadyChecked[a+limit][b+limit][c+limit] && a < limit && a > -limit && b < limit && b > -limit && c < limit && c > -limit) {
            alreadyChecked[a+limit][b+limit][c+limit] = true;
            int test = (int)Math.pow(a, 3) + (int)Math.pow(b, 3) + (int)Math.pow(c, 3);
            if(test == answer) {
                System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                System.out.println(answer);
                foundSolution = true;
            }else{
                printCubesOfNum(answer,limit,a+1,b,c,alreadyChecked);
                printCubesOfNum(answer,limit,a,b+1,c,alreadyChecked);
                printCubesOfNum(answer,limit,a,b,c+1,alreadyChecked);
                printCubesOfNum(answer,limit,a-1,b,c,alreadyChecked);
                printCubesOfNum(answer,limit,a,b-1,c,alreadyChecked);
                printCubesOfNum(answer,limit,a,b,c-1,alreadyChecked);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this code stops after it found **a** solution. There can be multiple solutions and there can also be no solutions.

You can check out a [similar question on mathoverflow here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways).

Answer (score 1):

> What I am asking are for […] maybe ways to have it search more systematically, starting at small integers and working its way up to bigger ones, […]

Instead of a `while`-loop, you might consider using nested `for`-loops:

```
for (int a = min; a < max; ++a) {
    for (int b = min; b < max; ++b) {
        for (int c = min; c < max; ++c) {
            int answer = (int) (Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3) + Math.pow(c, 3));
            if (answer == want) {
                System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                System.out.println(answer);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you don't actually need to try each possible value for *c*; rather, you know that *c*<sup>3</sup> = *want* − *a*<sup>3</sup> − *b*<sup>3</sup>; so you can just calculate that directly, and see if it works out:

```
for (int a = min; a < max; ++a) {
    for (int b = min; b < max; ++b) {
        // Note: the '0.1' is to be robust if there's some roundoff error:
        int c = (int) (0.1 + Math.pow(want - Math.pow(a, 3) - Math.pow(b, 3), 1.0/3.0));
        int answer = (int) (Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3) + Math.pow(c, 3));
        if (answer == want && c >= min && c <= max) {
            System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
            System.out.println(answer);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And for that matter, the symmetry of the problem (the commutative law of addition) means that we only need to try values of *b* that are at least equal to *a*:

```
for (int b = a; b < max; ++b) {
```

Another optimization is to avoid `Math.pow(..., 3)`, which is generally much less efficient than `... * ... * ...` (because `Math.pow` has to support non-integer exponents, so it works by taking a logarithm and an exponentiation):

```
int c = (int) (0.1 + Math.pow(want - a * a * a - b * b * b, 1.0/3.0));
int answer = a * a * a + b * b * b + c * c * c;
```

Yet another optimization is to restrict the range of *b*, in the inner for-loop, to only include values that would put *c* in the range of [*min*, *max*): we know that if *b* is too small, then *c* would have to be too big, and vice versa:

```
int minB = (int) (0.1 + Math.pow(want - a * a * a - max * max * max, 1.0/3.0));
if (minB < a) {
    minB = a;
}
int maxB = (int) (0.1 + Math.pow(want - a * a * a - min * min * min, 1.0/3.0)) + 1;
if (maxB > max) {
    maxB = max;
}
for (int b = minB; b < maxB; ++b) {
```

Of course, these sorts of optimizations can only take you so far. If you want to search a large range of integers, that will necessary take a lot of time. But the above should still be a massive improvement over what you have now.